# Repartition data back and forward from one administrative division to another: can't get the original data

Tags: partition, julia

I have some data relative to a certain administrative division, let’s say forest volumes per region.
I need to translate this data in a second definition of “regions”, and sometimes I need to do the opposite.

I have the region definition as raster ASCII grid files, so they are substantially a matrix of ids (integers) of the old and new regions.

I implemented a function (see code below) that optionally takes a third layer to consider the weight is this repartition (in my case it could be the forest cover) and returns a matrix of “conversion factors” and the “inverted” ones. My problem is however that when I test it with fake data and I go back, and forward I don’t obtain the original data. Why is it? I do have a loss of information so that I can’t recover the original data?

Here is a MWE script (the implementation is in Julia, but it doesn't really matter):

```
julia> using Pkg, Pipe, CSV, HTTP, DataFrames

julia> old_regions_url = "https://lef-nancy.org/files/index.php/s/LLWsWwMsDLez5pJ/download" # 100KB
"https://lef-nancy.org/files/index.php/s/LLWsWwMsDLez5pJ/download"

julia> new_regions_url = "https://lef-nancy.org/files/index.php/s/zZkPxw69JQgxoC8/download" # 100KB
"https://lef-nancy.org/files/index.php/s/zZkPxw69JQgxoC8/download"

julia> old_regions = @pipe HTTP.get(old_regions_url).body                                              |>
           CSV.File(_, delim=' ', datarow=7, header=false, ignorerepeated=true, missingstring="-9999") |>
           DataFrame                                                                                   |> 
           Matrix;

julia> new_regions = @pipe HTTP.get(new_regions_url).body                                              |>
           CSV.File(_, delim=' ', datarow=7, header=false, ignorerepeated=true, missingstring="-9999") |>
           DataFrame                                                                                   |> 
           Matrix;

julia> function compute_partitioning_factors(from_layer, dest_layer,part_layer=ones(size(from_layer)))
           from_list            = unique(skipmissing(from_layer))
           dest_list            = unique(skipmissing(dest_layer))
           partitioned_area     = [sum(skipmissing(part_layer[isequal.(from_layer,fr_el) .&& isequal.(dest_layer,dest_el)])) for fr_el in from_list, dest_el in dest_list]
           partitioning_factors = partitioned_area ./ sum(partitioned_area,dims=2)
           inverted_partitioning_factors = partitioned_area ./ sum(partitioned_area,dims=1)
           return partitioning_factors, inverted_partitioning_factors
       end
compute_partitioning_factors (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> partitioning_factors, inverted_partitioning_factors  = compute_partitioning_factors(old_regions, new_regions); # without considering the forest cover, just the regional area

julia> partitioning_factors
12×13 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.462863  0.0         0.537137     0.0         0.0         0.0  0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0        0.0         0.0         0.0
 0.0       0.997178    0.000940734  0.0         0.00188147  0.0  0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0        0.0         0.0         0.0
 0.0       0.0         0.0021322    0.995736    0.0         0.0  0.0         0.0         0.0021322   0.0        0.0         0.0         0.0
 0.0       0.00140647  0.0          0.0         0.998594    0.0  0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0        0.0         0.0         0.0
 0.0       0.0         0.0          0.0         0.0         1.0  0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0        0.0         0.0         0.0
 0.0       0.389881    0.0          0.0         0.00297619  0.0  0.0         0.605655    0.0         0.0014881  0.0         0.0         0.0
 0.0       0.0         0.0          0.0         0.464208    0.0  0.0         0.0021692   0.0         0.0        0.0         0.533623    0.0
 0.0       0.0         0.0          0.00293255  0.0         0.0  0.271261    0.0         0.725806    0.0        0.0         0.0         0.0
 0.0       0.0         0.0          0.0         0.0         0.0  0.00132802  0.00531208  0.0         0.992032   0.00132802  0.0         0.0
 0.0       0.0         0.0          0.0         0.0         0.0  0.0         0.0         0.00110865  0.0        0.998891    0.0         0.0
 0.0       0.0         0.0          0.0         0.00141844  0.0  0.0         0.997163    0.0         0.0        0.0         0.00141844  0.0
 0.0       0.0         0.0          0.0         0.0         0.0  0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0        0.0         0.0         1.0

julia> inverted_partitioning_factors
12×13 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  0.0          0.996008    0.0         0.0          0.0  0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0
 0.0  0.801209     0.00199601  0.0         0.00174978   0.0  0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0
 0.0  0.0          0.00199601  0.995736    0.0          0.0  0.0         0.0         0.00201207  0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0
 0.0  0.000755858  0.0         0.0         0.621172     0.0  0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0
 0.0  0.0          0.0         0.0         0.0          1.0  0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0
 0.0  0.198035     0.0         0.0         0.00174978   0.0  0.0         0.364695    0.0         0.0013369  0.0         0.0        0.0
 0.0  0.0          0.0         0.0         0.374453     0.0  0.0         0.00179211  0.0         0.0        0.0         0.997972   0.0
 0.0  0.0          0.0         0.00426439  0.0          0.0  0.994624    0.0         0.995976    0.0        0.0         0.0        0.0
 0.0  0.0          0.0         0.0         0.0          0.0  0.00537634  0.00358423  0.0         0.998663   0.00110865  0.0        0.0
 0.0  0.0          0.0         0.0         0.0          0.0  0.0         0.0         0.00201207  0.0        0.998891    0.0        0.0
 0.0  0.0          0.0         0.0         0.000874891  0.0  0.0         0.629928    0.0         0.0        0.0         0.0020284  0.0
 0.0  0.0          0.0         0.0         0.0          0.0  0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0        0.0         0.0        1.0

julia> testorig = [1,10,100,1000,1,10,100,1000,1,10,100,1000]
12-element Vector{Int64}:
    1
   10
  100
 1000
    1
   10
  100
 1000
    1
   10
  100
 1000

julia> reparted = (testorig' * partitioning_factors)'
13-element Vector{Float64}:
    0.4628632938643703
   15.277057271539391
    0.7597636600637447
  102.50611208723872
 1045.2047750859506
    1.0
  271.262325088697
  105.99509150047489
  726.0307577036091
    1.0069128248909125
    9.990241546747232
   53.50409993692404
 1000.0

julia> testorig2 = inverted_partitioning_factors * reparted # These are somehow similar but different than the original data !
12-element Vector{Float64}:
    1.219593965265186
   14.070517713047593
  103.5313287782654
  649.2638572678067
    1.0
   43.51153038770419
  444.96579344842854
  993.350156524107
    2.8549526600424606
   11.439992365183173
   67.79227689014971
 1000.0

# When I call the function with the inverted new/old region definition I can find back the "inverted" partitioning factors:
julia> partitioning_factors2, inverted_partitioning_factors2  = compute_partitioning_factors(new_regions,old_regions);

julia> partitioning_factors2' == inverted_partitioning_factors
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhmm.. I think I got which is the "problem".

This repartition method (that I understood takes the name of [Modified Areal Weighting - Control Zones](https://lig-membres.imag.fr/plumejeaud/publis/geog-an-mod_13-01-2010_CP-v8.pdf) assumes that the data is homogeneous within the region.

When I convert data from the "old" to the "new regions, I am assuming homogeneity across the old regions, but not the new ones.

At the same time when I am transferring back the data I am assuming homogeneity, but this time across the new ones, so the results I have back are not the same.

I wonder if I should spend time (or if a published method already exists) to consider and weight the homogeneity of both the regional definitions, the old "regions" and the new ones..